# Bounding box coordinates taking into consideration (but not applying) rotation

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, transforms

I am trying to make a script that will determine the exact coordinates of an object's bounding box in the render. (I later want to limit the rendered space to that area.)

So far I managed to get the coordinates from the object's `bound_box` And I managed to take the scale and location into account but I failed with the rotation.

My problem is that I have the coordinates of my bounding box but I don't know how to make them follow the rotation, like the bounding box in the viewport does. When I run the script with a cube it works fine, but when the cube is being rotated the coordinates that are being printed out do not change.

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import mathutils

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.object
co = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location

scale = bpy.data.objects['cube'].scale

bounding_box_vertices = []
for i in range(8):
    bounding_box_vertices.append(i)
    bounding_box_vertices[i]=[1, 2, 3]

#the Coordinates from bound_box are saved to bounding_box_vertices[[],[]]
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(3):
        bounding_box_vertices[i][j]=bpy.data.objects['cube'].bound_box[i][j]*bpy.data.objects['cube'].scale[0] + bpy.data.objects['cube'].location[j]

def rendered_coords(x):
    co = mathutils.Vector((bounding_box_vertices[x][0], bounding_box_vertices[x][1], bounding_box_vertices[x][2]))
    co_2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, obj, co)

    render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
    render_size = (int(scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale), int(scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale))
    #print("Pixel Coords:", (
    return([round(co_2d.x * render_size[0]), round(co_2d.y * render_size[1])])
     # ))

#prints ou the 8 X and Y coordinates that the bounding box would have on the render (even though its invisible of course)
for i in range(8):
    final_coords = rendered_coords(i)
    print(final_coords[0])
    print(final_coords[1])
```

Comment: @R.M They are talking about coordinates in the render, hence the 'rendering' tag is relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounding box coordinates of `obj.bound_box` are in local space. To convert them to world space – assuming you're interested in the world space coordinates and don't just want to consider rotation – you'll have to **multiply the world matrix with the coordinates** as mentioned in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6172/34236) by *CoDEmanX*.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.object  # or bpy.data.objects['cube']
bb_vertices = [Vector(v) for v in obj.bound_box]
mat = obj.matrix_world
world_bb_vertices = [mat * v for v in bb_vertices]
```

From there you can continue with [`world_to_camera_view`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy_extras.object_utils.html). From your code it's not clear what your `obj` is, but just to clarify: This function takes the **Camera** object and not the object with the bounding box. The bounding box coordinates are only considered for the third parameter. Similarly, you will need the `mat` world matrix of the object with the bounding box.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view
from mathutils import Vector

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.object  # or bpy.data.objects['cube']
bb_vertices = [Vector(v) for v in obj.bound_box]
mat = obj.matrix_world
world_bb_vertices = [mat * v for v in bb_vertices]

co_2d = [world_to_camera_view(scene, scene.camera, v) for v in world_bb_vertices]  # from 0 to 1

render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
render_size = list(int(res) * render_scale for res in [scene.render.resolution_x, scene.render.resolution_y])
pixel_coords = [(c.x * render_size[0], c.y * render_size[1]) for c in co_2d]  # in pixels

for p in pixel_coords:
    print('{p[0]:.0f}, {p[1]:.0f}'.format(p=p))
```

Comment: In newer version of python element-wise multiplication is now using * so for matrix multiplication use @ - PEP465 https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/